# How to fix this npm install dependency issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I'm trying to add `npm install react-material-ui-carousel --save` to my react project. However when I try to install I get this dependency tree issue.

- I have alredy deleted the lock and npm modules files, followed by `npm install` the whole project. Still getting this same error below however.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: buckets@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.11.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.9.11" from react-material-ui-carousel@2.2.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-material-ui-carousel
npm ERR!       react-material-ui-carousel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@material-ui/icons)
npm ERR!   2 more (react-dom, @material-ui/icons)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-material-ui-carousel@2.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-material-ui-carousel
npm ERR!   react-material-ui-carousel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-03-02T19_57_57_671Z-debug.log
```

My other dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chartist": "^0.10.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-chartist": "^0.14.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.14.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

The other option I could try is  `--legacy-peer-deps`, but I would only do that as a last result option if nothing else works.

How can I properly fix the dependency tree error to get `react-material-ui-carousel` to install in my project?

Comment: You could downgrade to to `react@^16.0.0` or submit a PR to `react-material-ui-carousel` to upgrade to `react@^17.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Add `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` at the end of your command.
Like such: `npm install react-material-ui-carousel --save --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

"peerDependencies":{ "react": "^17.0.1"} add this in your package.json

Comment: I've tried adding it but still getting the same error